# Animation in AngularJS Directive, event not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to do something after an 'enter' event in a directive. The event isn't firing when the template is loaded in.

Here is the app declaration

```
angular
  .module('MyApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
      })
      .when('/in-the-community', {
        templateUrl: 'views/in-the-community.html',
        controller: 'CommunityCtrl'
      })
       .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

Initially I am using the routing provider to give me a template page. I am then trying to use a directive inside these templates to provide another view. This works by using the following in my template page

```
<div class="flex">
    <div class="fc fci image-wrapper" id="home-banner">
    </div>

    <div class="fc fcc">
        <section show-and-hide-content="{{ sub_content }}">
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

This loads in the following directive

```
angular.module('rubisApp')
  .directive('showAndHideContent', function ($animate) {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'views/community-sub.html',
      controller: 'CommunitySubCtrl',
      link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
        $animate.on('enter', element,
           function callback(element, phase) {
             console.log('attributes.showAndHideContent');
           }
        );
       }
     };
   });
```

The console log isn't running and I can only presume that is because it isn't firing the `$animate.on` event.

Does angular apply the `ng-enter` class to a `templateUrl` in a directive?

I'm pretty new to angular so if this is the wrong way of doing this, an alternative would really help also.

Comment: never heard of a `enter` event before and cannot find smth about it via google - did you mean when "enter-key" is pressed?

Comment: @messerbill, `enter` is an angularjs structural event, @ChrisTownsend what is `container`? Do you have it defined somewhere that you are not showing? Or did you mean to use `element`?

Comment: No, so with the animate provider, when using ng-view it adds classes during different states. I'm trying to do it with a directive and do something as a callback

Comment: @PatrickEvans I don't have it defined anywhere but don't have any errors. I have now changed it to element, but still no event running

Comment: If you weren't getting a `Uncaught ReferenceError: container is not defined`  or similar error than your `link` callback isnt even being called

Comment: @PatrickEvans yeah I did initially think that but if I remove the $animate event and just place a console.log in, it fires. The container attribute just came straight out of the docs.

Comment: The link function will be called of course, so you get the console output when there is no event required. Regarding the enter event: Is there a component visible which you actually can enter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $animate dependency as not being pulled into the directive.

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .directive('showAndHideContent',['$animate', function ($animate) {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'views/community-sub.html',
      controller: 'CommunitySubCtrl',
      link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
        $animate.on('enter', element,
           function callback(element, phase) {
             console.log('attributes.showAndHideContent');
           }

        );

      }

     };
   }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

i see you are using an controller. can't you create the event there?
I checked my code and have this snippet on controller, to destroy an interval when route changes, notice that i use $on and '$destroy', with $. can it be that?

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                    $interval.cancel($scope.interval);
                });
```